# What is the right way to store BitBake configuration under git?

Tags: configuration, git, yocto, version-control, bitbake

What is correct way to keep track of bitbake configuration and used layers in git?

Answer (score 9):

Here's what I find works best:

- Make new, empty git repository e.g. `my-yocto` on a drive with at least 50 GB of free space.
- Add [poky](https://git.yoctoproject.org) as a [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) of `my-yocto`.

```
git submodule add git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky.git
```

- From `my-yocto` root, run:

```
source poky/oe-init-build-env .
```

Note the "." in that command; initializing the build environment in `my-yocto` instead of `poky` prevents Yocto's GB of temp files from accumulating under `poky`.

- The script will create a directory `conf` in `my-yocto` with some files in it; git-add `conf/local.conf` and `conf/bblayers.conf` to your repo.
- By default, yocto sets up `bblayers.conf` using absolute paths, which means a repo set up by Alice won't work on Bob's machine. Fix that by modifying `bblayers.conf` using the Yocto `${TOPDIR}` variable:

```
(...)
BBLAYERS ?= " \
  ${TOPDIR}/poky/meta \
  ${TOPDIR}/poky/meta-poky \
  ${TOPDIR}/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
(...)
```

- Edit `local.conf` to a supported platform in e.g `MACHINE=beaglebone-yocto`
- From `my-yocto`, run `bitbake core-image-minimal` . Make sure your computer is well-ventilated and go for a hike.

If that works, you can build out the rest of your configuration by adding meta-openembedded etc. as submodules. I recommend any custom layers be distinct git repos from `my-yocto`, so that `my-yocto` only contains the git submodule details and the bitbake configuration.

To update before building, run:

```
git pull
git submodule update --remote --recursive
```

Other users will need to run `git submodule init` one time after cloning `my-yocto`.

Two other recommendations:

First, if you build for more than one machine, create a local.conf for each machine and create a symbolic link from local.conf to the machine-specific conf file. This allows you to track multiple machines in `my-yocto`.

Second, create a temp directory for each yocto branch (e.g. `tmp-zeus`, `tmp-dunfell`, `tmp-gatesgarth`) and then make a symbolic link from `tmp` to whichever branch you are building. (Don't add these to git.) Yocto accumulates an enormous amount of data in the `tmp` directory, and it requires you to clean out `tmp` when you switch branches. That's fine if you move to a newer release, but if you switch back and forth between branches it's a bummer to lose all of that cached data.